# Why would one put `#! /usr/bin/false` in a Perl Module?

Tags: perl, cpan

I was looking at the source code for the CPAN Perl module `Digest::Perl::MD5` and noticed that it has the she bang `#! /usr/bin/false`. Here's the first few lines of `Digest/Perl/MD5.pm` ...

```
#! /usr/bin/false
#
# $Id: MD5.pm,v 1.19 2004/02/14 02:25:32 lackas Exp $
#

package Digest::Perl::MD5;
use strict;
use integer;
use Exporter;
use vars qw($VERSION @ISA @EXPORTER @EXPORT_OK);
```

... why would the author of Digest::Perl::MD5 use `#! /usr/bin/false`? And what if my system does not have `/usr/bin/false` but has `/bin/false` instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> why would the author of Digest::Perl::MD5 use #! /usr/bin/false?

So that if someone tried to use the module as an executable (`Perl $ ./MD5.pm`), it would quietly die instead of trying to execute the module as a program.

> And what if my system does not have /usr/bin/false but has /bin/false instead?

Then it will nosily die complaining that it couldn't find `/usr/bin/false` if anyone tried that.

Comment: Quentin is entirely correct.  I would add that any shebang line in a `.pm` file is entirely optional and not normal.  99% of the time, Perl modules are not installed in the `PATH` and will not have executable permission.  Occasionally, you might also see a module with a `#!/usr/bin/env perl` shebang line, which usually indicates that the module _could_ be executed (to run built-in tests for example).  But unless you have a really unusual situation, I would not put a shebang line in a `.pm` file.  It only raises questions (like yours) for future readers.

Comment: The only reason the `#!/usr/bin/false` shebang was even noticed by me was that I was packaging the Perl module in a RPM and when I attempted to install the RPM yum refused to install it because of a missing dependency on `/usr/bin/false`.  I went ahead a simply patched `MD5.pm` to `/bin/false` and re-packaged.  Thanks for all the comments and replies!